# adding a Font Awesome icon to phone_number_link helper and display inline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hey all I am having a bit of an issue with adding a Font Awesome telephone icon to a helper method I used from a tutorial and not too sure how to proceed.

I am looking to achieve something like this:

[image]

but so far have only managed to create the telephone number as a clickable link.

the helper method:

```
  def phone_number_link(text)
    sets_of_numbers = text.scan(/[0-9]+/)
    number = "+1-#{sets_of_numbers.join('-')}"
    link_to text, "tel:#{number}"
  end
```

and the link its self:

```
<li><%= phone_number_link("(587) 841-0708") %></li>
```

Im just not sure how to add the icon into this equation. Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated!

please let me know if you require any further information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<li><i class="icon-phone"></i><%= phone_number_link("(587) 841-0708") %></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have included the font awesome css properly (and we should verify that), you should only have to do this:

```
<i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

... so in the context of your code it would look like this:

```
<li>
    <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i><%= phone_number_link("(587) 841-0708") %>
</li>
```

Here's the [Font Awesome phone icon](http://fontawesome.io/icon/phone/)